# How to use a property in multiple view controllers defined in a single file?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uikit

I made a function to make a circular animation. Function takes radius:float as input. I have done this in a ViewController Class and it is working fine for that view controller. But now i want to use this animation on multiple view controllers and don't want to write the same code on every single view controller. So i want to know how can i make this function in a separate file in such a way that i only need to call the function with the radius and it will do the work. Or can you tell me the best practice to do that.
Thanks in advance.

//

I dont want to do it in myViewController i just want to create a new class only for circular animation. and also dont want to import that class want to do like this-

```
import UIKit
class CircularProgressView {
    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    public func createProgressView(radius:CGFloat,forView:UIView) {
        let center = forView.center
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 2*CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
        forView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        forView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        forView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))
    }
    @objc private func handleTap() {
        print("hello s")
        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        basicAnimation.toValue = 1
        basicAnimation.duration = 2

        basicAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "basic")
    }
}
```

and use this like-
import UIKit

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        CircularProgressView().createProgressView(radius: 50, forView: view)
    }

}
```

but in this code guesture recogniser is not working.

Comment: inherited all your view controllers from viewController where you implemented your animation

Comment: can you provide an example.

Comment: @PiyushSharma please see the answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a `UIViewController` `extension` and add a method `animate(with:)` in it with the relevant code,

```
extension UIViewController {
    func animate(with radius: Float) {
        //add your code here..
    }
}
```

The method `animate(with:)` is now available to all `UIViewController` subclasses. So, you can simply call it like so

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.animate(with: 10.0)
    }
}
```

There is no need to create any parent `class` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new swift file called BaseViewController

```
import UIKit
class BaseViewController : UIViewController {
    //Add your animation code
}
```

And inherit from this new file

```
import UIKit 
class YourVC : BaseViewController {
  // do your stuff here
}
```

Another way to do it is by creating an extension.

```
extension UIViewController {
   func doAnimation() {
      // do your stuff here
   }
}
```

And to use it.

```
view.doAnimation()
```

You can also have look at [Swift Documention](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html) on Inheritance

Comment: You don't need to subclass a view controller to reuse a view.

Comment: @Desdenova updated my answer with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example of how you can do it. Hope it helps

```
    class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func startCircularAnimation(radius: Float) {
        // your animation code here
    }

}

class FirstViewController: MyViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startCircularAnimation(radius: 25)
    }

}

class SecondViewController: MyViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startCircularAnimation(radius: 30)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you try to call function once for to use  whole view controllers.
In order to achieve that you can create Manager class.
 with Manager.Instance.callFunction you can use your animations inside  every controller class.

```
class Manager {
    private static let _instance =  Manager()



     static var  Instance: Manager{

        return _instance
    }

    private init(){

    }
  func callFunction(){

 // add animation stuff.

    }
```

Comment: @PiyushSharma I saw your edited question. My answer is correct. Inside your viewController viewDidLoad call this Manager.Instance.callFunction.

Comment: put all your CircleProgress process inside to callFunction.